# Isomorphism in Clifford semigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

If I take a subsemilattice $S'$ of the Clifford semigroup $S$, such that the groups of $S'$ are abelian by finite of finite index in the respective groups of $S$ and I want to prove that $S$ is permutable. Does there exists an isomorphism from $S$ to $S'$?

Comment: Could you please (1) give the missing definitions and notation (permutable, structure maps) and (2) ask only one question. Before asking your questions, did you consider the case where $S$ is a group?

Comment: Let S be a semigroup and $n$ integer greater than 1.   A sequence ${s}_{1},{s}_{2},...{s}_{n}$, of $n$ elements of S is called permutable
if the product ${s}_{1}{s}_{2}...{s}_{n}$, remains invariant, under some nontrivial permutation of its factors, that is, there 
exists a permutation $\sigma  \in S_{n}$ different from the identity, such that ${s}_{1}{s}_{2}...{s}_{n}={s}_{\sigma(1)}{s}_{\sigma(2)}...{s}_{\sigma(n)}$

Comment: If $E$ is a semilattice, then a strong semilattice of groups is a collection of groups $\{H_e$ with $e\in E\}$ together with the group homomorphisms $\nu _{e,e\prime }:H_{e}\rightarrow  H_{e\prime }$ for every $e\geq e'$ satisfying the following conditions.


 For every $e\in E$, $\nu _{e,e}$ is the identical homomorphism of $H_e$
 For every $e_1\geq e_2\geq e_3$, $\nu _{e_{2},e_{3}}\nu_{e_{1},e_{2}}=\nu _{e_{1},e_{3}}$

Comment: Can someone help ?!

Comment: @J.-E.Pin The case when $S$ is a group holds. I am interested to investigate the case when $S$ is Clifford semigroup.

Comment: @ http://math.stackexchange.com/users/89374/j-e-pin

Comment: @ J.-E.Pin: The case when SS is a group holds. I am interested to investigate the case when SS is Clifford semigroup? Can you please give me a hint?